# Fourier Transform in $l^2(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Let $x\in l^2(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})$, we consider the fourier transform:
$$F^*:l^2(\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{C})\rightarrow L^2([02\pi]\rightarrow\mathbb{C})$$
$$\mathcal{(F^*x)(y)}:=\sum_{n\in\mathcal{Z}}x_ne^{iny}$$

I need to prove that it's an isomorphism,

So first, is it well defined? if $||\sum_{n\in\mathcal{Z}}x_ne^{in(.)}||_{L^2}< \infty ?$

Comment: The functions $y\mapsto e^{iny}$ are an orthonormal system in $L^2(0,2\pi)$. That should help to show that $F^*$ is an isometry.